# Apache CXF: Kerberos client configuration are not picked up when using JaxWsProxyFactoryBean

Tags: spring, web-services, cxf, kerberos

Apache CXF Version 2.7.10
WSS4J Version 1.6.14
Spring 4.0.1.RELEASE

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer"/>

<cxf:bus>
    <cxf:features>
        <p:policies/>
        <cxf:logging/>
    </cxf:features>
</cxf:bus>

<http:conduit name="https://myhost.*">
    <http:tlsClientParameters disableCNCheck="true">
        <sec:keyManagers keyPassword="password">
            <sec:keyStore type="JKS" password="password" resource="keystore.jks" />
        </sec:keyManagers>
        <sec:trustManagers>
            <sec:keyStore type="JKS" password="password" resource="keystore.jks"/>
        </sec:trustManagers>
        <sec:cipherSuitesFilter>
            <sec:include>.*_EXPORT_.*</sec:include>
            <sec:include>.*_EXPORT1024_.*</sec:include>
            <sec:include>.*_WITH_DES_.*</sec:include>
            <sec:include>.*_WITH_AES_.*</sec:include>
            <sec:include>.*_WITH_NULL_.*</sec:include>
            <sec:exclude>.*_DH_anon_.*</sec:exclude>
        </sec:cipherSuitesFilter>
    </http:tlsClientParameters>
</http:conduit>

<jaxws:client name="{http://my.namespace/}SOAPDelegatorServicePort"
            serviceClass="a.b.c.d.SOAPDelegatorService" serviceName="s:SOAPDelegatorService"
            endpointName="s:SOAPDelegatorServicePort" xmlns:s="http://my.namespace/"
            address="https://myhost:8443/delegator/api/soap" wsdlLocation="wsdl/delegator.wsdl"
            createdFromAPI="true">
    <jaxws:properties>
        <entry key="ws-security.kerberos.client">
            <bean class="org.apache.cxf.ws.security.kerberos.KerberosClient">
                <constructor-arg ref="cxf"/>
                <property name="contextName" value="JaasContextName"/>
                <property name="serviceName" value="HTTP@ServiceName"/>
                <property name="callbackHandler">
                    <bean class="com.sun.security.auth.callback.TextCallbackHandler" />
                </property>
            </bean>
        </entry>
        <entry key="mtom-enabled" value="true"/>
        <entry key="auth.spnego.useKerberosOid" value="true"/>
    </jaxws:properties>
</jaxws:client>

<bean id="soapDelegatorClientFactory" class="org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsProxyFactoryBean">
    <property name="serviceClass" value="a.b.c.d.SOAPDelegatorService" />
    <property name="address" value="https://myhost:8443/delegator/api/soap" />
</bean>

<bean id="soapDelegatorClient" class="a.b.c.d.SOAPDelegatorService" factory-bean="soapDelegatorClientFactory" factory-method="create" />
```

I am expecting that Apache CXF will make my kerberos config in **jaxws-client** be available on my JaxWsProxyFactoryBean. As it turns out, that's not the case. I get the error below:

```
javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: These policy alternatives can not be satisfied: 
{http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702}TransportBinding: Received Timestamp does not match the requirements
{http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702}IncludeTimestamp: Received Timestamp does not match the requirements
{http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702}Layout
{http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702}SupportingTokens: The received token does not match the supporting token requirement
{http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702}KerberosToken
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:157)
    at $Proxy66.executeRequest(Unknown Source)
    at a.b.c.d.webServiceClientTest(WebServiceIntegrationTest.java:81)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
Caused by: org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.SoapFault: These policy alternatives can not be satisfied: 
{http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702}TransportBinding: Received Timestamp does not match the requirements
{http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702}IncludeTimestamp: Received Timestamp does not match the requirements
{http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702}Layout
{http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702}SupportingTokens: The received token does not match the supporting token requirement
{http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702}KerberosToken
    at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.Soap11FaultInInterceptor.unmarshalFault(Soap11FaultInInterceptor.java:84)
    at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.Soap11FaultInInterceptor.handleMessage(Soap11FaultInInterceptor.java:51)
    at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.Soap11FaultInInterceptor.handleMessage(Soap11FaultInInterceptor.java:40)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:272)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.AbstractFaultChainInitiatorObserver.onMessage(AbstractFaultChainInitiatorObserver.java:113)
    at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.CheckFaultInterceptor.handleMessage(CheckFaultInterceptor.java:69)
    at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.CheckFaultInterceptor.handleMessage(CheckFaultInterceptor.java:34)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:272)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.onMessage(ClientImpl.java:835)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.handleResponseInternal(HTTPConduit.java:1614)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.handleResponse(HTTPConduit.java:1504)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.close(HTTPConduit.java:1310)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.AbstractConduit.close(AbstractConduit.java:56)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit.close(HTTPConduit.java:628)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.MessageSenderInterceptor$MessageSenderEndingInterceptor.handleMessage(MessageSenderInterceptor.java:62)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:272)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.doInvoke(ClientImpl.java:565)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:474)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:377)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:330)
    at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxy.invokeSync(ClientProxy.java:96)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:135)
    ... 27 more
```

Answer (score 1):

The http conduit name is not the conduit address, You need to change the http:conduit name just like this

```
<http:conduit name="*.http-conduit" />
```